# Google Maps API IOS cannot load new coordinates with custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I have a problem with loading coordinates for a custom UIView that has been linked through IBOutlet and subclassed as GMSMapView. The mapView loads but it always shows the wrong location every time (always London as I presume that is the default). But if I change self.mapView to self.view, the coordinates load correctly within the map. I have no clue why loading coordinates with a custom UIView doesn't work while using the superview works. Thank you in advanced!

```
@IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!

 override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    let kCameraLatitude = 37.314617900000002
    let kCameraLongitude = -121.7901318
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(kCameraLatitude,
                                                      longitude: kCameraLongitude, zoom: 1)
    let newMapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(self.mapView.frame, camera: camera)
    self.mapView = newMapView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it by changing the view camera only as such:

```
@IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!

 override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    let kCameraLatitude = 37.314617900000002
    let kCameraLongitude = -121.7901318
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(kCameraLatitude,
                                                      longitude: kCameraLongitude, zoom: 1)
    self.mapView.camera = camera
}
```